# How to replace images?

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails

I seem to have a problem with editing and replacing images in Wordpress. Do they automatically replace the image if it has the same file name or is a new file name(copy) always created?

Also if I bulk upload via cPanel to the image directory does this create problems as thumbnails are not created?

Answer (score -1):

1. They will replace the original image but if you are using thumbnails you will need to regenerate them because otherwise the thumbnails will be of the previous image.
2. Yes, you need to manually regenerate them.

You can use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for the task.